# How to validate a URL via a check constraint in Postgres?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Here is one of the many check expressions I've tried:

```
(url::text ~* 'https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,255}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)'::text)
```

Which never works.

And yet oddly enough this does (for email validation):

```
(email::text ~* '^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$'::text)
```

I'm not sure what the difference between these two check expressions is, though I'd love to know.

**So how can I validate a URL via a check constraint in Postgres?**

Comment: What do you mean by "never works". What is happening, and what are you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: In general when validating things like this, you're usually better off having a more basic expression. Something super simple like '^https?://'. Otherwise in the future when you inevitably find a URL coming your way that doesn't fit your regex exactly, now you have to go make *schema* changes. Best if you can have your business logic or even UI layer do this kind of validation. It's also worth noting bulk inserts will be slowed down.

Comment: @mroach thanks! That's really helpful. I was expecting the constraint to reject the insert/update if the url wasn't a proper regex and accept the insert/update if the url is a proper regex.

Comment: I'm confused.  You say that you want to match a URL, but  you give a pattern that matches an email.

Comment: What does a backspace (`\b`) does in a URL validating pattern? The [word boundary in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) is `\y` (or `\m` and `\M` for beginning and end of a word). Also, without `^` and `$` your regexp just validates that the input *contains* an URL, not that itself is an URL. I also suggest you to use a simpler pattern than that. But maybe consider supporting [IDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) too.

Comment: @pozs very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think I was trying to understand what the difference between the two is, why one would work, and the other wouldn't. That's a hefty question to answer though, and I think I could have framed it better.

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed your expression for URL validation with help of comment below the question.
So, just for sharing:

```
(website :: text ~* 'https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,255}\.[a-z]{2,9}\y([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)$' :: text)
```

Comment: I had to tweak the regex a bit to allow for anchors & query strings:

`CREATE DOMAIN url AS text
CHECK (VALUE ~ 'https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,255}\.[a-z]{2,9}\y([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.,~#?!&>//=]*)$');
`

Comment: Looks like escaping forward slashes is not necessary in PostgreSQL POSIX regex pattern matching: `select ('https://' ~ '^https://');` evaluates to `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the URL regex from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/191438) into a Postgres check. This ought to handle any valid URL.

```sql
CHECK ((url ~ '^[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9\+\.])*:(?:\/\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~!\$&''\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\/\?])*)?'::text))
```

Comment: This marks `a:` as a valid url. It's not a very robust expression